# Oracle sql developer : what is the fastest way to copy a partition of table to other partition with different table

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have two table t1 and t2. Both are identical and have same partitions.

We can say clone of each other. Now one of the job executed and fill one of the partition p in 4 hrs in t2 table.

In the end of the job i want to copy/cut/move all the data from that partition to t1 partition p.

Right now i am using the insert command but it is taking 30 mins time for 10 million records.

`Insert into t1 select * from t2 partition p;`

Can we do anything in little time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table to "exchange through". From 12.2 `create table for exchange` simplifies this.

For example:

```
create table src ( c1 ) 
partition by range ( c1 ) (
  partition p0 values less than ( 11 )
) as
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select * from rws;
  
create table dst ( c1 ) 
partition by range ( c1 ) (
  partition p0 values less than ( 11 )
) as
  select * from src
  where  1 = 0;
  
create table tmp 
  for exchange with table src;
  
select count(*) from src;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        10

select count(*) from dst;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
  
alter table src
  exchange partition p0 
  with table tmp;
  
alter table dst
  exchange partition p0 
  with table tmp;
  
select count(*) from src;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

select count(*) from dst;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        10
```

For more details on this, see my recent Ask TOM Office Hours on [archiving data](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?oh=17423)

Comment: create table tmp 
  for exchange with table src; it is not working in oracle sql developer

Comment: Which version of Oracle Database are you using? You can create the temp using standard `create table`; you need to be sure the source table has no hidden columns though

Comment: It is oracle sql developer 20.4

Comment: SQL Developer is the client; you need the database version `select * from v$version`

Comment: It is 12.1, i created the table using create table. But now i have to drop constraint from t1 table. Now i am afraid if i drop the constraint, it might be possible that some job can put the duplicate records

Comment: Why do you have to drop the constraint?

Comment: Sql developer not allowing to put the value without dropping constraint. Say if i am first exchanging t2 with temp table, then my t2 table contains contraint.... this process is successful. But after that if i exchange t1 with temp then it is not allowing me to exchange without dropping constraint

Comment: Submit a new question showing the steps you took and the error you got

Answer (score -1):

consider [Partition exchange](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E08650B4-06B1-43F9-91B0-FBF685A3B848.htm) functionality. Assuming you want to move:

`ALTER TABLE t2 EXCHANGE PARTITION p WITH TABLE t1;`

This requires for the table to have identical columns with the same data type, name, order, indexes, etc.

Comment: But t2 contains many partitions , we need to copy exactly p partition from t2 table to t1

Comment: Ignore the above comment,  what will happen to data present in t2 table partition p

Comment: Do you copy or move? The approach above swaps partition p from table t2 with the corresponding partition in table t1. This means that if t2.p has 1M rows and t1.p has 0 rows, in the end t2.p will have 0 rows and t1.p will have 1M rows.

Comment: It works only with non partioning table

Comment: @sparsh610, Not really. It also allows for partitions to be exchanged between two tables with partitions. See example https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-8E3836CA-6C40-4058-88C1-9D14E410128F.htm. In this example a hash partition from one table is swapped with the corresponding partition of another - compatible - table.

Comment: In my table partition is list

Comment: Those use cases are supported and examples are provided as well.

Comment: @chegancasb - you can't transfer one partition between two partitioned tables. Either you swap a non-partitioned table with one partition, or _all_ the partitions in a table with a partition and its subpartitions. The example you've referenced is swapping both partitions in `t1` for the subpartitions of the partition `p1` in `t2`